# qsub with conda activate?

Tags: conda, qsub

I would like to submit job with `qsub` and do `conda activate myenv`

Other posts suggested `source activate myenv` but didn't work in my case.

Log from cluster showed : `.../node16/job_scripts/7102106: line 8: activate: No such file or directory`

Any idea how to do `conda activate` with `qsub` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the shebang `#!/bin/bash -l`? That would be the cleanest solution (assumes you've configured `conda init bash`). Otherwise, try adding the line, `. /path/to/your/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` to the script.